# NEST Query for exact text matching

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to write a NEST query that should return results based on exact string match. I have researched on web and there are suggestions about using Term, Match, MatchPhrase. I have tried all those but my searches are returning results that contains part of search string.
For example, In my database i have following rows of email addresses:

ter@gmail.com

ter@hotmail.com

terrance@hotmail.com

Irrespective of whether i use:

```
client.Search<Emails>(s => s.From(0)
                        .Size(MaximumSearchResultsSize)
                        .Query(q => q.Term( p=> p.OnField(fielname).Value(fieldValue))))
```

or

```
  client.Search<Emails>(s => s.From(0).
                              Size(MaximumPaymentSearchResults).
                              Query(q=>q.Match(p=>p.OnField(fieldName).Query(fieldValue))));
```

My search results are always returning rows containing "partial search" string.

So, if i provide the search string as "ter", I am still getting all the 3 rows.
ter@gmail.com

ter@hotmail.com

terrance@hotmail.com

I expect to see no rows returned if the search string is "ter".If the search string is "ter@hotmail.com" then i would like to see only "ter@hotmail.com".

Not sure what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your email field?

Comment: Thanks Val for your response. The issue was mappings as you and Russ have indicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided in the question, it sounds like the field that contains the email address has been indexed with the **[Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)**, the default analyzer applied to string fields if no other analyzer has been specified or the field is not marked as `not_analyzed`.

The implications of the standard analyzer on a given string input can be seen by using the [**Analyze API**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) of Elasticsearch:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=ter%40gmail.com
```

The text input needs to be url encoded, as demonstrated here with the @ symbol. The results of running this query are

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "ter",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "gmail.com",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

We can see that the standard analyzer produces two tokens for the input, `ter` and `gmail.com`, and this is what will be stored in the inverted index for the field.

Now, running a [**Match** query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) will cause the input to the match query to be analyzed, by default using the same analyzer as the one found in the mapping definition for the field on which the match query is being applied.

The resulting tokens from this match query analysis are then combined by default into a **boolean or** query such that any document that contains any one of the tokens in inverted index for the field will be a match. For the example

text `ter@gmail.com`, this would mean any documents that have a match for `ter` or `gmail.com` for the field would be a hit

```
// Indexing
input: ter@gmail.com -> standard analyzer -> ter,gmail.com in inverted index

// Querying
input: ter@gmail.com -> match query -> docs with ter or gmail.com are a hit!
```

Clearly, for an exact match, this is not what we intend at all!

Running a [**Term** query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) will cause the input to the term query to ***not*** be analyzed i.e. it's a query for an exact match to the term input, but running this on a field that has been analyzed at index time could potentially be a problem; since the value for the field has undergone analysis but the input to the term query has not, you are going to get results returned that exactly match the term input as a result of the analysis that happened at index time. For example

```
// Indexing
input: ter@gmail.com -> standard analyzer -> ter,gmail.com in inverted index

// Querying
input: ter@gmail.com -> term query -> No exact matches for ter@gmail.com

input: ter -> term query -> docs with ter in inverted index are a hit!
```

This is not what we want either!

What we probably want to do with this field is set it to be `not_analyzed` in the mapping definition

```
putMappingDescriptor
    .MapFromAttributes()
    .Properties(p => p
        .String(s => s.Name(n => n.FieldName).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
    );
```

With this in place, we can search for **exact matches** with a [**Term** filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) using a [**Filtered** query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

```
// change dynamic to your type
var docs = client.Search<dynamic>(b => b
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(fq => fq
            .Filter(f => f
                .Term("fieldName", "ter@gmail.com")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which will produce the following query DSL

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "fieldName": "ter@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed the issue.

Comment: No probs, happy to help!

Comment: An attribute on the property sorted this for me, but you let me to the answer (PS: `[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]`)

Comment: @DavidG some simpler mapping can be expressed with attributes, but the fluent API is able to map everything available in the Elasticsearch mapping API. Glad it led you to the answer :)

Comment: @Russ Cam, how to make this solution work for  NEST 7.6.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740162/how-to-make-elastic-engine-understand-a-field-is-not-to-be-analyzed-for-an-exact

Answer (score 4):

You can also do a MatchPhrasePrefix query to get an 'Exact' match performed.

```
.MatchPhrasePrefix(ma => ma.Field(field).Query(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the "Bool Query" with "Match Phrase Prefix Query" to get an exact match.

```cs
var boolQuery = new BoolQueryDescriptor<MyClass>();

boolQuery.Must(must => must
   .MatchPhrasePrefix(matchPhrasePrefix => matchPhrasePrefix
      .Field(f => f.Title)
      .Field(f => f.Description)
      .Query(text)
   )
);
```