# How to do an exact match query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do an exact match query to an ElasticSearch index,
**I have the following data -**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.21110919,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.21110919,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "test"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.160443,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "test two"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to query the field `name`,
I am trying to search the name `test`,
But it returns me both documents.

The expected result is the only document `1`.
**Mapping is as follows -**

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I tried the following -**

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term" : { 
          "name": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the mapping

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740162/how-to-make-elastic-engine-understand-a-field-is-not-to-be-analyzed-for-an-exact/60750951#60750951) answer might help.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant added the index mapping

Comment: Check my answer below and the link to answer in above comment has detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `text` datatype on your `name` field, which is spitting `test two` in 2 tokens as `test` and `two`, hence it matches your search query `test` **as `match` query is analyzed and applies the same analyzer to resultant tokens are matched against the documents tokens present in the inverted index.**

**Solution your using example**

### Index def

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword" --> note use of `keyword` type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Index you sample docs

```
{
   "name" : "test two"
}

{
   "name" : "test"
}
```

### Search query same as yours

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

### Search results as you want

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so_key",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.6931471,
            "_source": {
               "name": "test"
            }
         }
      ]
```

**Important Note:** you can use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see how your data is indexed, for example

### Using standard(default analyzer) on the text field

POST _analyze

```
{
    "text": "test two",
    "analyzer" : "standard" --> Change analyzer to keyword and see diff
}
```

### Tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "two",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the link to the answer I provided in comment, I would suggest you to define name field as:

```
{
   "name":{
      "type": "text",
      "fields":{
         "keyword":{
            "type": "keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and then query on field `name.keyword` whenever you require exact match (case sensitive) and `name` if you want partial match such as search on first name only.